# Elasticity of collisions in Relativity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, elasticity

Is it possible that collisions which are elastic in the rest frame of reference are inelastic or partially elastic in some other constant velocity frame? If you need to invoke general relativity here, that is also welcome.

Comment: Do you know the Lorentz transformations for energy and momentum? If so, you could try applying them to an elastic collision to see whether the collision is elastic in other frames.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you asking if it's possible for two things to collide and stick together as observed in some inertial coordinate system but not stick together as observed from some relatively moving one?

Comment: Sarvottam Singh, I lightly edited your question. Please revert if you're not happy with it.

Comment: How could a mere coordinate change (like a Lorentz transformation) affect the underlying physics?

Comment: Are we talking about particles, or hypothetic perfectly elastic extended objects (e.g. balls of wakanadium)...because SR rules out the latter.

Comment: @JEB We are talking about real objects, which relativity prohibits to be rigid, here. So things like metal, rubber or wood. But for the sake of specificity Lets us say we are talking about "balls"(or close to spheres) of diamond.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hmmmm, that's why I was asking if someone knows or has worked on a specific problem, where something resembling that happens. I understand the postulate present. I was asking if it's possible that in any specific scenario something akin to that happens.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes, something like that. But I will not be too specific about the sticking together part. I Would present it as. "does coefficient of restituition changes at all with coordinate transformation" ? thanks

Comment: @G.Smith i have used SR and 4vector conservation of momentum and energy but that didn't give any relevamt result. That's why I asked if someone has worked on General relativistic collisons. I know GR only to the point of field equations, but if something else is needed i would read that too.

Comment: You don’t need GR for this.

Comment: If you have information that makes your question more clear, then you should [edit] it into the question, don't bury it down here in the comments. BTW, your diamond balls don't know or care what coordinates you're using. ;)